# how to separate numbers by asterisks c#

Tags: c#

I don't understand how to do this im new to programming but im sure its simple. help the code I have so far is:
I need the asterisks to be separating the numbers

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine("********");
```

but the asterisks is only showing at the bottom

Comment: I don't think there is any programming language for which this syntax works.  You either need braces or indents, and you have neither.

Comment: actually this code is perfectly legal C# code (albeit indented in an unorthodox way and not producing the results the OP wanted). I'm not sure why it was put on hold?

Answer (score 3):

You should put the body of the loop into a scope:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
   Console.WriteLine("********");
}
```

Otherwise only the following next command is interpreted as the body of the loop, equivalent to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
Console.WriteLine("********");
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it is only doing the for loop on the first line. You need to put both lines into a 'block' using curly braces:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Console.WriteLine("********"); 
}
```